# update table with history keeper of the updated records in a new column

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I need to log the updated columns into an existing empty column in which it should appear "Updated" or "Not Updated". I am running this query in MS Access.
Below find an example for my update query (which works) and code for the trigger (not sure i need one, or if i'm using it correctly)

```
update my_table
set col_i_need_to_set = 'value'
WHERE another_col like 'some_text' 
and another_col2 LIKE 'some_other_text'
and another_col3 LIKE 'text'


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER historyKeeper
  AFTER UPDATE my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( UPDATING( 'col_i_need_to_set' ) )
  THEN
    INSERT INTO my_table( column_in_which_i_want_to_insert, column_value )
      VALUES( 'Updated');
else 
 INSERT INTO my_table( column_in_which_i_want_to_insert, column_value )
      VALUES( 'Not updated');
  END IF;
END;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, found the solution. after `set col_i_need_to_set = 'value'` I just need to add , `column_in_which_i_want_to_insert = 'UPDATED'` Maybe this will help someone